# How to convert value in dataframe to value

Tags: python, dataframe

Very new to coding in python, but I am trying to understand how to convert a value in a dataframe to a simple value without that structure. I am doing this because I pulled a value from SQL and am passing that into a function that doesn't accept data frames, but my SQL query result is stuck in the dataframe.

Details below:

I ran a two queries to pull the first latitude and longitude values from a data table.

```
nyc= bq_helper.BigQueryHelper(active_project= "bigquery-public-data", 
                                   dataset_name = "new_york")

query_lat = """
SELECT latitude from `bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_stations`
limit 1
"""

query_long = """
SELECT longitude from `bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_stations`
limit 1
"""
```

Then I assigned the query result to lat and long variables

```
lat = nyc.query_to_pandas_safe(query_lat)
long = nyc.query_to_pandas_safe(query_long)
```

I want to pass these into a folium mapping function

```
map_hooray = folium.Map(location=[lat, long],
                    zoom_start =11)
```

But, I get an error that the folium function does not accept dataframes.

How do I convert the value in the dataframe into a simple value that I can pass into the folium function?

I am working in a python in a Jupyter notebook on Kaggle

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not having more information Im not sure how to answer your specific question, but you can acquire a specific value with iloc.

`df.iloc[1,3]`

However, for your case, it may be more helpful to iterate down a row or column and pull the specific values per row, as it is likely multiple values are being returned if it is being returned in a dataframe.

```
df = lat.merge(long, left_index = True, right_index = True)

map_hooray = []
for key, row in df.iterrows():
    long = row['long']
    lat  = row['lat']
    map_hooray.append(folium.Map(locations = [lat, long], zoom_start = 11))
```

or even better, after merging:

```
df['Map'] = df.apply(lambda x: folium.Map(locations = [x['lat'], x['long']], zoom_start = 11))
```

Answer (score 1):

For what you appear to be doing, I'm not sure you need to use Pandas dataframe.

Something like:

```
lat = query_lat.fetchone()
long = query_long.fetchone()

map_hooray = folium.Map(location=[lat[0], long[0]], zoom_start =11)
```

May work for you.
Unless of course you need the dataframe for other purposes.